# What corporations can I run missions for and avoid losing standings with the major factions?

Tags: eve-online

What factions are there in EVE that you can run agent missions for that either don't lose you faction with the four major nations, or at least bring up such missions infrequently?

Since I last played CONCORD and Jove have had their agents taken off the grid.

To my knowledge, Servant Sisters of EVE is the only one left (and all their combat mission agents I know of have been turned into distro agents) but I'm curious if there are others.

Please indicate what security region (high, low, null) the agents occur in.

Answer (score 2):

Eh I wouldn't say that Sisters are neutral, or at least they weren't a few months when I played last. They give you gallante with minor bonus to minmatar.

Can't say that I've ever ran into factions that were neutral. If your'e trying to keep your totals with factions from being lopsided, only thing I could suggest would be grab a minor corp (aka no navies) with decent lvl4's in the amarr/caldari, and the gallante/minmatar camps and mission back and forth.

If you decide to do so, be carefull to accept only the missions where targets are pirates, or non-faction ships, else it would be a huge blow for your standings.

Comment: couldn't say it better. It's quite impossible to be friendly to all factions (except if you just mission between all of them).

Comment: Perhaps I should review my standings again, but when I was grinding SoE earlier I only occasionally got missions against the Caldari State (which I assumed was a bug since I'd also get missions against CONCORD).  Perhaps I should re-phrase my question as "How do I avoid getting missions against navy opponents where simply shooting them lowers my standing with an empire faction."

Comment: If that's your question, then [http://eve-survival.org/] is your answer. Check the mission title before you accept it, and if it involves faction navy, decline.